# Install jetstream and livewire in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I am using PHP 7.3, Laravel 8.0, Node version 13.13.0 and NPM version 6.14.4.

**When I install Jetstream v2.9 and Livewire, the CSS in the login and register page has broken**.

I used below command's :

```bash
composer require laravel/jetstream 
php artisan jetstream:install livewire 
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

- [Registration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ1Fs.png)
- [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdNA0.png)

I tried to reinstall another node version. and added it in layout `guest.blade.php` and `app.blade.php`

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
<script src="{{asset("js/app.js")}}" defer></script>
```

However, the same error occurs. Any Suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app

cd example-app

composer require laravel/jetstream

php artisan jetstream:install livewire

php artisan jetstream:install livewire --teams

php artisan jetstream:install inertia

php artisan jetstream:install inertia --teams

php artisan jetstream:install inertia --ssr

php artisan jetstream:install livewire --dark

npm install
npm run build
php artisan migrate

Comment: try using this commands